# Double pointer as argument to execvp()

Tags: c, shell, execvp, double-pointer

I am trying to execute `execvp()` using a custom `**tokens` double pointer as input, instead of `argv[]` on a "create a custom shell" assignment, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(){
    char *token;
    char **tokens = malloc(sizeof(char*)*512); //512 is for the maximum input-command length
    char *command=malloc(sizeof(char)*512);
    int i = 0;
    pid_t child_pid;
    int status;
    //***********take input from user*************************************
    fgets(command,512,stdin);

    //***********parse input*********************************************
    token = strtok(command," \t");

    while( token != NULL ) {

        tokens[i]=token;
        i ++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " \t");

    }
    child_pid = fork();

    if(child_pid == 0) {
        /* This is done by the child process. */
        execvp(tokens[0], tokens);
    } else {
        waitpid(child_pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
    }
}
```

The problem is definately on this line:

```
execvp(tokens[0], tokens);
```

and I just can't understand why **it can't be executed and print to my** `stdout`.
I have tried this:

```
execvp("ls", tokens);
```

and it works just fine.
And this:

```
printf("%s\n", tokens[0]);
```

with the output being (according to the test input: `ls` ):

> ls

Comment: `char **tokens = malloc(sizeof(char)*512);` the size argument is incorrect. `tokens[i]=token;` the tokens array should be terminated with a null pointer.

Comment: I 've tried putting this line after the `while`  loop :  
` tokens[i] = NULL;`  
still doesn't work

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: The code presented never assigns a value to `child_pid`.  If that's a local variable then its value is therefore indeterminate when you test it.  Did you mean to `child_pid = fork();` before checking the pid?

Comment: My bad. Forgot to put the line. Fixed

Comment: The code is now complete and it fully reproduces the problem

Comment: The `WUNTRACED` option is not needed here.  Use 0 for the third argument.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but it is needlessly complicated to allocate memory dynamically for `tokens` and `command`.  You allocate them to fixed, small sizes known at compile time, and never do anything fancy like reallocating them, so it would be easier and more natural to declare them as arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems in your code, including:

1. The array of argument pointers passed to `execvp()` must be terminated by a null pointer.  You do not ensure that.
2. The string obtained via `fgets` will include all characters up to and including the line's newline, if the buffer is large enough to accommodate it.  You do not include the newline among your token delimiter characters, so for a one-word command `ls`, the command passed to `execvp()` is equivalent to `"ls\n"`, *not* `"ls"`.  It is unlikely (but not impossible) that `ls\n` is an available command on your machine.
3. You do not check the return value of `execvp()`, or of any of your other functions, nor do you handle any errors.  `execvp()` is special in that it returns only if there is an error, but you would have saved yourself some confusion if you had handled that case by emitting an error message.

After I correct the first two of those, your program successfully runs an "ls" command for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate the memory with `sizeof(char *)`.

```
char **tokens = malloc(sizeof(char *)*512);
                                   ^^----------->Size of char pointer
```

As of now you are allocating `sizeof(char)` thus invoking undefined behavior.

---

Also consider the first comment pointed by @[n.m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m)

Comment: Still after this edit, it won't print to my terminal